# It's Possible To Run Windows Mobile 5 SDK In Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, windows-7, sdk, windows-mobile-5.0

I was seeing about [Windows Mobile 5 SDK at Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=83A52AF2-F524-4EC5-9155-717CBE5D25ED&displaylang=en) and I also see some requirements to run it:

> System Requirements
>
> - **Supported Operating Systems**: Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1; Windows XP
> - Visual Studio 2005 Standard, Professional, and Team Suite Editions

And I only have my Visual Studio 2008 Professional and Windows 7, but it's possible to use the SDK with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit and Studio 2008 Enterprise and it works just fine. (also works fine on Vista Business 32-bit and XP Pro).

Comment: I have Windows 7 Ultimate 32-Bit and Visual Studio 2008 Professional, then I think it will run fine **;)**

Answer (score 1):

Should be OK!  They are minimum requirements.

Comment: But remember that the Windows 7 and Vista architeture are different from Windows XP, the same thing for Visual Studio.

Comment: What version of Windows 7 do you have?  There is always XP mode if you run into any problems.